# Update callback when using datastore and subject behaviour (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

First post. Im quite new to Angular. I've done some searching about this but havn't found (?) an answer.

Before i subscribed directly to the get/post/put functions that contacted the API and returned the value. When doing that i could handle the callback directly in GUI.

This approach was not the best as i needed the data to be shared between multiple components.

I ended up creating data stores. The problem is now that i still need the callback after doing for example: update().

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks !

In service:

```
private _projects: BehaviorSubject<Project[]>; 
private serviceUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/api/project`;

private dataStore: { 
    projects: Project[]
};

get projects() {
    return this._projects.asObservable();
}

constructor(private http: HttpClient, public listener: ProjectListenerService, public authService: AuthService) {
    super();

    this.dataStore = { projects: [] };
    this._projects = <BehaviorSubject<Project[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
}

public loadAll() {
    return this.http.get<Project[]>(this.serviceUrl).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError),
        map(res => res.map(v => new Project(v)))
    ).subscribe(data => {
        this.dataStore.projects = data;
        this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
    }, error => console.log('Could not load projects.'));
}

public update(project: Project) {
    let payLoad = { Data: project, ConnectionId: this.listener.ClientConnectionId, HubAction: "AllExcept" };

    this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${project.id}`, payLoad).subscribe(data => {
      if (typeof data == typeof true) {
        this.dataStore.projects.forEach((t, i) => {
          if (t.id === project.id) { this.dataStore.projects[i] = project; }
        });

        this._projects.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).projects);
      } else console.log('Could not update project.');
    }, error => console.log('Could not update project.'));
}
```

In component:

```
this.projectService.loadAll();

//Here i update a project, but i want to be able to do things after the update, like updating GUI. 
this.projectService.update(project);

//What i want to do... 
this.projectService.update(project).subscribe(data=>{
 //Do some gui stuff, do another update etc etc..
});

this.projectService.update(project).then()... etc
```

Comment: Have you looked at NgRx? It is a design pattern used by Angular devs for creating and managing your application store and state. You can find out more about it here: https://ngrx.io/

Comment: I haven't ! Thanks for the link. Will read up more on NgRx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be adding another parameter to `update` that will be the callback you call after `this._projects.next`.

A more "Rx" solution would be using `share()` or `shareReplay()` and returning the shared Observable.

```
public update(project: Project) {
  const shared = this.http.put(...).pipe(
    shareReplay(),
  );

  shared.subscribe(data => {
    ...
  });

  return shared;
}
```

Then you can subscribe to the returned Observable and update GUI as you want.

```
this.projectService.update(project).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will use the first option. When trying to use the second more "Rx" solution, i do not get the function to subscribe on the shared obj. It only has unsubscribe, add and remove.

Comment: Are you sure you tried `return shared;` and not `return shared.subscribe(...)`? These are two different things.